# Android Emulator won't start up

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I ran my android emulator, I got the following black window. I waited for a long time and nothing came up.

There is also no logs in the eclipse console.

I am sorry this is not informative.. If you point me to a location for log files I would love to prove more information.

[EDIT] sorry if I weren't clear. I meant to ask, for thsi sort of emulator problem, other than trial and error, how do I really *diagnose* it? where is the log file I can trace down to?

[image]

Comment: What is the spec of the machine you are running it on? Also, did you set the AVD to have a large SD card? If so, don't do that as it tries to allocate real/virtual memory of the actual size - just set it to the amount of SD card your app actually needs. Also what version of Android is the AVD set to use - newer versions are bulky. As Little Child mentions the AVD can take a long time to start - a v4.x emulator on my ageing WinXP system can take up to 10 minutes on first run although using a snapshot reduces that significantly on subsequent re-runs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on OSX, I've solved that by :

1. Go to `.android` directory (in my case it was `Users/<username>/.android`
2. Go to `avd` folder
3. Find the emulator that won't start (directory name will be the same as emulator)
4. Remove all .img files from there. Do not remove .ini files.
5. Try to run the simulator again.

Comment: Beware, on windows this blue-screens the machine (for me).

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you do not have enough RAM. It does take up a lot of time to start up if you are running it for the first time. What I suggest is using [`Genymotion`](http://www.genymotion.com/) as it is way faster than Android stock emulator.

If you insist on using the stock emulator, make sure the `save snapshot` option is checked so that the emulator starts up faster the next time.